# Save input data to localStorage on button click

Tags: html, button, input, local-storage

I am trying to build my first web application. In my app I need to have a settings panel, but I have no idea how to do it. I've been searching the web and came across a HTML5 localStorage, which I believe might be the best way to do the things. But the problem is I have no idea how to use it.

```
<input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer"/>
```

How can I save data from input to localStorage when user clicks the button? Something like this?

```
<input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer"/>  

<button onclick="save_data()" type="button">Save/button>

    <script>
            function saveData(){
        localStorage.saveServer
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) object has a `setItem` method which is used to store an item. It takes 2 arguments:

1. A key by which you can refer to the item
2. A value

   ```
   var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
   localStorage.setItem("server", input.val());
   ```

The above code first gets a reference to the `input` element, and then stores an item ("server") in local storage with the value of the value of that `input` element.

You can retrieve the value by calling `getItem`:

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server");
```

Comment: so like this?  

<label for="serveri"> Server: </label>


  <input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer"/> 
 

<button onclick="save_data()" type="button" value="Save" id="Save" data-theme="a">Save</button>


    <script>

           function saveData(){

       var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");

localStorage.setItem("server", input.value);

var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server");

        }
 
        </script>

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to save the value of multiple inputs and have them stay inside the input until I pressed a clear button and cleared them?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. For setting I placed `.value` behind the `var` and called the `var` in the `setItem`:

```
var input = document.getElementById('saveServer').value;
localStorage.setItem('server', input);
```

For getting the text back:

```
document.getElementById('saveServer').value = localStorage.getItem('server');
```