# save input values to localstorage & "bind" it with HTML element

Tags: jquery, local-storage, advanced-custom-fields

I painted this picture to demonstrate what my final goal is.

[image]

**Short description:**

- If nothing is changed in form or there's already exact same values saved, **"save values" button** does nothing
- If something is changed in form, **"save values" button** saves those values to localStorage and bind with numbered element (**"1" in picture**) and with input it came from
- If numbered element is clicked, it fills the inputs that were changed with values that were saved
- If something is changed in form & it's not the same as already saved values, **"save values" button** saves to element 2
- **Red "X"** in numbered element deletes saved values from localStorage binded to that element

---

Im not here to get the whole working solution from you guys, don't worry. I've researched for a week & I can't wrap my mind around it. It would be easy without binding to elements & "grouping".

**Questions:**

- How to bind localStorage values to numbered elements **and also** to input fields it first came from?
- How to "treat" saved values in localStorage as group which is binded to numbered element? For example: delete values only binded to that numbered element if delete is pressed.
- How to check if same values already exist (also taking into account many values, it's easy with 1)?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333230/save-input-data-to-localstorage-on-button-click) shows how to set & get value to/from localStorage.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed) shows how to remove value from localStorage.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-is-set) shows how to check if localStorage value exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have worked out in the course of the chat that ensued [the first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32547623/1) of my answer that there is basically a bunch of HTML form elements [that all have unique IDs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25675984#25675984).

On that premise it's relatively easy to grab them and store them into an object as key/value pairs. This object then represents the state the form was in at that point in time.

So we need two functions - one that turns the values in an HTML form into an object, and one that does the opposite (with a little bit of smarts regarding the types of form elements it is dealing with). These functions could look like this:

```js
function getFormState() {
    var formState = {};

    $(".form-control, :input:hidden").each(function () {
        formState[this.id] = $(this).val();
    });
    return formState;
}

function setFormState(formState) {
    $.each(formState, function (key, value) {
        var $target = $("#" + key);
        if ( $target.is(".ui-datepicker") ) {
            // set datepicker value...
        } else if ( $target.is(":text") ) {
            $target.val(value);
        } // etc for other field types
    });
}

$(function () {
    var savedState = {testinput: "Hello!"};

    setFormState(savedState);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="testinput">
```

Saving the `formState` object would involve serializing it as JSON and putting it into localStorage, that's not overly complicated, either.

Comment: Sorry if I expressed myself in a way that I only needed jQuery. I actually need any kind of solution that would work with logged-in users and visitors even after they close the browser & come back later. I'll look into your solution and let you know.

Comment: @AWA I assumed that jQuery wasn't a hard requirement. That wouldn't have made sense.

Comment: I ran to dead-end. My form is kind of dynamic (& complex) because I add fields with [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) & code mostly uses `foreach cases` to decide input type, structure etc. After watching few tutorials about knockout.js, Im finding it extremly difficult to add it to my solution.. I might (or not) overcome this eventually but could you help me to understand saving/getting/removing "group of data" to localStorage using knockout.js by updating your answer?

Comment: My answer already contains that. It contains a "group" (i.e., an array) of values. And it shows how to turn the entire thing into JSON, which means you can save it anywhere you like, localStorage included.

Comment: Now I don't know ACF, but from the documentation it looks like it does most of the work on the server. This is unfortunate, because knockout is a client framework. It is geared towards creating HTML at run-time on the client all by itself, it does not work well with server-generated HTML. This looks like a showstopper to me. Maybe you are able to extract something of value from http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-countrycitystate-field/ - the associated git repository claims to have localStorage support.

Comment: I've debated about scrapping ACF before, I might just do that in near future & hard-code all inputs. This leaves only few questions: **1.** How to approach to different types of inputs? **2.** Current solution gives search results via ajax if checkbox is checked, something is written into textbox etc. Could this be a showstopper?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89510/discussion-between-tomalak-and-awa).